# Ошибка "Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array" при использовании ActiveForm в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

**Модель:**

```
class Film extends FilmBase
{
    public function getProducers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AllProducers::class, ['producer_id' => 'producer_id'])->viaTable('film_producers', ['film_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $film = Film::findOne($id);
        $allProducers = ArrayHelper::map(AllProducers::find()->all(), 'producer_id', 'producer');
        $filmProducers = $film->getProducers()->all();


        if ($film->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
            && $filmProducers->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $isValid = $film->validate();
            $isValid = $filmProducers->validate() && $isValid;

            if ($isValid) {

                $film->save(false);

                foreach ($filmProducers as $filmProducer) {
                    $modelProducer = new FilmProducers();
                    $modelProducer->film_id = $film->id;
                    $modelProducer->producer_id = $filmProducer;

                    $modelProducer->save(false);
                }

                return $this->redirect(['film/view', 'id' => $id]);
            }
        }
```

**Форма:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($film, 'imgUpload')->fileInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($film, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($film, 'preview')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($film, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($filmProducers, 'producer[]')->widget(Select2::class, [
    'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], $allProducers),
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Выберите режиссера...',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
])->label('Режиссер'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Ошибка:** Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array

**Вопрос:** Как сделать в форме мультиселект, в котором отображались бы уже сохраненные в БД данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($film, 'producer')->widget(Select2::class, ...
```

И сохранение данного поля придется делать ручками

Comment: Пробовал так, все равно ошибка.
Ругается на переменную ***$allProducers*** в этой строке:
    'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], $allProducers),

Comment: Что за ошибка??

Comment: Пустое значение для выпадающего списка делается путем добавления значения `'prompt' => ''`,  в массив `options`. Тогда в `data` достаточно сделать указать `'data' => $allProducers,`

Comment: Ошибка та же - **Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array**

Comment: попробовал вариант с ' 'prompt' => '' ', в массив 'options' и ' 'data' => $allProducers,' все равно ошибка **Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array **

Comment: Ошибка в контроллере, у Вас c мульти селекта приходит массив выбранных `id`, Вам надо вручную заполнять модели, а не делать так `$filmProducers->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

Comment: Да и здесь делать `$isValid = $filmProducers->validate() && $isValid;`:  `ValidateMultiple`

Comment: И здесь `$modelProducer->producer_id = $filmProducer;` как Вы в поле таблицы записываете объект?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, понял куда смотреть.
Понимаю, что вопрос был тупой, но только начинаю работать с Yii и пока много туплю...